# How to get back button on a new page I added?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am using navigation template and get a default home page. I add another page called home2, nothing changed yet everything what I get out of VS. From home, I can go to home2. Problem is from home2,I don’t see that back button to get back to home. In my home2.html, I have following

```
<button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
```

Not sure I can enable it so that I can see it in home2. If I remove the disabled from above line, I do get it but when I click on it, I still am on same page. I am not sure what I need to add to get back button functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how are you getting to home2?

If you use WinJS.Navigation.navigate('/pages/home2/home2.html') this should all work automatically and your back button is available.

If you are using an href, then you'll need to hook into the href and in turn call navigate instead of letting the href work as it normally would, otherwise you aren't using the navigation framework. If you have questions on that - I'll post more but let's first see what you are doing.

Comment: Actually your tip did the trick. I was doing through href. Per your suggestion I create the hook and used Navigation.navigate. Everything working fine now. Thanks for your help :)